# Cordova project run in android mobile but not in android studio emulator

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-android

I am trying to run hello world cordova project.
I am able to run this project in mobile phone but while I am trying to run using android studio emulator, it throw error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
47 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 46 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\Users\vinay\AndroidStudioProjects\Cordova\hello\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
No target specified, deploying to device '4172aa4d'.
none
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\Users\vinay\AndroidStudioProjects\Cordova\hello\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Using apk: C:\Users\vinay\AndroidStudioProjects\Cordova\hello\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Package name: com.example.hello
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

Android studio version- 3.0.1 , cordova version 8.0.0,
Cordova requirements

```
C:\Users\vinay\AndroidStudioProjects\Cordova\hello>cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle
```

Please help me to find out what I am missing.

**EDIT**
Updated after ***Christian Wico*** response:

I tried to run

```
cordova run android --emulator
```

Now it throw another error

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
47 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 46 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\Users\vinay\AndroidStudioProjects\Cordova\hello\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat" sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat" avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

(node:10860) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your first code group is a SUCCESS message. The other one is just environment info. **Where is the error message?***

Unless there is an absolute need to deploy your project using Android Studio, **you should use the Cordova CLI to launch your apps**.

To launch, you administer the following command from within your project directory:

```
cordova run android
```

The command will preferably launch the app from within an attached device. Should you wish to explicitly tell the CLI to launch into an emulator, use the `--emulator` flag along with your `run` command:

```
cordova run android --emulator
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Please check updated post.

Comment: Can I run this project in Window 10?
As I cannot attach my android phone to test android app.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is by restarting the emulator.